# Foselasticabundle : method returns empty results

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch, foselasticabundle

I use Elasticsearch with Foselasticabundle to search in my Symfony app, but it returns empty results.
This is my config and search method:

foselasticbunde.yml:

```
  indexes:
       search:
           finder: ~
           client: default
           types:
               course:
                   mappings:
                       id: ~
                       title: ~

                   persistence:
                       driver: orm
                       model: AppBundle\Entity\Course
                       finder: ~
                       provider: ~
                       listener: ~
```

SearchController.php

```
 public function elasticSearchAction(Request $request)
    {
        $query = $request->get('q');
        $finder = $this->container->get('fos_elastica.finder.search.course');
        $results = $finder->find($query);
        return new JsonResponse($results);
    }
```

But it returns this empty results:

```
[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]
```

Whats the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: Did you populate the index?

Comment: yes, I used this command: `php app/console fos:elastica:populate`

Comment: Try to check if the $query is not empty. echo $query

Comment: @AmiraBedhiafi No, It's not empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Results is an array of objects, I changed my code:

```
public function elaSearchAction(Request $request)
{
    $query = $request->get('q');

    $finder = $this->container->get('fos_elastica.finder.search.course');
    $results = $finder->find($query);

    $data = array();
    foreach ($results as $course){
        $data[] = array(
            'id' => $course->getId(),
            'title' => $course->getTitle(),
            'description' => $course->getDescription(),
        );
    }

    return new JsonResponse($data);
}
```